# Connect with a Swift client to a Java server using sockets

Tags: java, sockets, client, swift

How do I connect a Swift client to a Java server using sockets?
How can I send different data types between the client and the server?

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(12345);

        while(true) {

            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            System.out.println(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream())).readLine());

        }
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried to do.  Normal Socket IO should be fine.

Comment: Start here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/UsingSocketsandSocketStreams.html

Comment: I have already read that but I am new to swift sry. Can anybody guide me through that?

Comment: Can anybody help me? plss

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SocketRocket ObjC framework bridged to Swift

https://github.com/square/SocketRocket

Then you just create an instance of the class and use it in Swift, i.e.:

```
var socket = SRWebSocket(...)
socket.open()
socket.send()
socket.close()
```

Example:

You create a NSURLRequest:

```
var urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://host.com"))
```

then init the socket with it

```
socket = SRWebSocket(URLRequest: urlRequest)
```

No need to link the framework, just import the files

[image: SocketRocket sources]